# NumPy.percentile cannot take 'interpolation' even I have upgraded it to the latest version

Tags: python, numpy

Our project is using it in code as:

```
W_percentile[x, y] = np.percentile(np.array(l), 75, interpolation='lower')
```

But I keep getting error:

```
**TypeError: percentile() got an unexpected keyword argument 'interpolation'**
```

I saw some answer says it's due to old version of numpy. But my numpy version is 1.10.1. Has anyone any idea why I'm getting this error? thanks!

Comment: Can you give us a reproducible code fragment that prints `np.__version__`, performs the percentile operation on self contained data and include the full error? This should indeed work with the latest numpy version.